# Authentication on different oidc schemes

Tags: identityserver4

I have a proxy that is openid client.
On the proxy I have configured two schemes:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Bearer";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc-app1", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://sts.com";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "app1";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc-app2", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://sts.com";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "app2";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
```

Theese scheme differ only in ClientIds: app1 and app2.

My client selects scheme depending on request:

```
                string clientId = GetClientIdFromContext(context);
                string schema = $"oidc-{clientId}";

                var userResult = context.AuthenticateAsync(schema);
                var user = userResult.Result.Principal;

                // Not authenticated
                if (user == null || !user.Identities.Any(identity => identity.IsAuthenticated))
                {
                    return context.ChallengeAsync(schema);
                }
                else
                {
                    return next();
                }
```

Authentication on scheme "app1" is successful.

When I authenticate on scheme "app2":
- identity server issues token
- when processing http://proxy/signin-oidc I'm getting error "Not authenticated"

Probably this error comes from that code:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication\RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs:

```
                // The SignInScheme may be shared with multiple providers, make sure this provider issued the identity.
            string authenticatedScheme;
            var ticket = result.Ticket;
            if (ticket != null && ticket.Principal != null && ticket.Properties != null
                && ticket.Properties.Items.TryGetValue(AuthSchemeKey, out authenticatedScheme)
                && string.Equals(Scheme.Name, authenticatedScheme, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(ticket.Principal,
                    ticket.Properties, Scheme.Name));
            }

            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Not authenticated");
```

but I cant debug that.

Can you help me?
Can you explain this comment "The SignInScheme may be shared with multiple providers, make sure this provider issued the identity."?

Thanks for help
Best wishes :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. In such situations you have to have different callback paths for every provider:
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1510